# Angular2/ NodeJS project structure and CORS issue

Tags: node.js, angular, jakarta-ee, cors

I have been developing JEE web app using Spring Boot and jQuery so far and this is the first time I am developing a NodeJS/ Angular2 app. In JEE application, both client as well as server side component gets compiled into a single jar/ war file. However, in my new development environment, I am developing client and server side as two separate projects (listening to different ports) and calling the backend url from Angular2 service layer. I am having Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue.

My question is, is this common practice to develop Angular and NodeJS as two separate application and resolve the CORS issue through using cors module in NodeJS?

I found some solution as below from Node side:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

So, I appreciate if you can help me clarify

1. Right project structure in this architecture
2. Recommended resolution for the CORS issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is quite common to use two separate projects in for the front- and backend. But this doesn't mean it's the best or only way to do it. It always depends on your specific requirements and the size of your project. For smaller projects it's probably easier to have both projects in the same repository, but this is a personal preference.

Regarding CORS it really depends on what you are trying to do. Just because you have two separate repositories doesn't mean that you have to serve them on different domains/ports. For example, you could use nginx to route the requests to your API or frontend depending on the url. If they are not hosted on the same domain/port you have to disable CORS, as you said. Try to make the rules as strict as possible and only allow your specific domain.

Comment: Thanks a ton for tour response. It clarifies a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, could you please accept it? Thanks!